# How do I fetch the response from an apiCall to display in my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Basically I have my AuthContext, with my reducer, actions and apicalls.

AuthReducer:

```
        case "LOGIN_FAILURE":
        return {
            user: null,
            isFetching: false,
            error: true,
        };
```

AuthActions:

```
export const loginFailure = () => ({
type:"LOGIN_FAILURE",
```

});

ApiCalls:

```
export const login = async (user, dispatch) => {
dispatch(loginStart());
try {
    const res = await axios.post("/auth/login", user);
    dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
} catch (err) {
    dispatch(loginFailure());
}
```

};

and the actual call in my api:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        !user && res.status(401).json("Wrong password or username!");

        const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        const originalPassword = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        originalPassword !== req.body.password &&
        res.status(401).json("Wrong password or username!");

        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
            { id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin },
            process.env.SECRET_KEY,
            { expiresIn: "5d" }
        );

        const { password, ...info } = user._doc;

        res.status(200).json({ ...info, accessToken });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json();

    }
});
```

and in my component:

```
    const handleLogin = (e) => {
    if(email.match(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/g)){
        login({email, password}, dispatch);
        e.preventDefault();
        history.push("/");
    }
};
```

Everything works wonderfully. Now when I enter the wrong login credentials, obviously nothing happens. In the chrome console under Network -> Response, I get my "Wrong Username or Password". But how do I fetch the 401 response to display it in my component, so I can display it over my login Button IF I enter the wrong login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try implementing the [Toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify) into your project, import it into the `Log In` component

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
```

, whenever you get 401 condition, as I see in your code, around here:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
!user && res.status(401).json("Wrong password or username!");
```

and here:

```
originalPassword !== req.body.password &&
res.status(401).json("Wrong password or username!");
```

just implement the `toast.error('Your desire error')` into it, you don't have to rework the code or anything so much and I think you're good to go.

Comment: I cant implement it into my auth.js tho... it says 
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

and If i implement it in my login component, I cant write toast.error('Your desire error') in the auth.js file, so it happens on wrong username or password.

Comment: You can try to go to the `package.json` and add the `{ "type": "module" }` to it, it will ensure that all .js and .mjs files are interpreted as ES modules.

Comment: then my other 
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

things wont work though I think

Comment: Oh, then remove the `type: "module"`, my bad. You are not using import-export as I normally do, let's me find if there's someways to implement it using your way.

Comment: @lorijames95 Can you try to create a new file, like `toastifyNotfi.js` or something like that and `import { toast } from 'react-toastify'` only? Will it work? Or something like this. `const toast = require('toast') from 'react-toastify'`